# Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, json, casting, twitter

I am getting the following exception when I try to deserialize a JSON response from Twitter API. It sometime went through but sometime have an issue.

Below are the classes:

```
public static List<Tweet> Newtwt = new List<Tweet>();

public class Url2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string expanded_url { get; set; }
    public string display_url { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
}

public class Url
{
    public List<Url2> urls { get; set; }
}

public class Description
{
    public List<object> urls { get; set; }
}

public class Entities
{
    public Url url { get; set; }
    public Description description { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string screen_name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public Entities entities { get; set; }
    public bool @protected { get; set; }
    public int followers_count { get; set; }
    public int friends_count { get; set; }
    public int listed_count { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public int favourites_count { get; set; }
    public int utc_offset { get; set; }
    public string time_zone { get; set; }
    public bool geo_enabled { get; set; }
    public bool verified { get; set; }
    public int statuses_count { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public bool contributors_enabled { get; set; }
    public bool is_translator { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_image_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_image_url_https { get; set; }
    public bool profile_background_tile { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url_https { get; set; }
    public string profile_link_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_sidebar_border_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_sidebar_fill_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_text_color { get; set; }
    public bool profile_use_background_image { get; set; }
    public bool default_profile { get; set; }
    public bool default_profile_image { get; set; }
    public object following { get; set; }
    public bool follow_request_sent { get; set; }
    public object notifications { get; set; }
}

public class Entities2
{
    public List<object> hashtags { get; set; }
    public List<object> symbols { get; set; }
    public List<object> urls { get; set; }
    public List<object> user_mentions { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public object id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public bool truncated { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_status_id { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_status_id_str { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_user_id { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_user_id_str { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_screen_name { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public object geo { get; set; }
    public object coordinates { get; set; }
    public object place { get; set; }
    public object contributors { get; set; }
    public int retweet_count { get; set; }
    public int favorite_count { get; set; }
    public Entities2 entities { get; set; }
    public bool favorited { get; set; }
    public bool retweeted { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public bool? possibly_sensitive { get; set; }
}

public class Tweet
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public object ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "created_at")]
    public DateTime TwitTime { get; set; }
}
```

And I try to deserialize the response in the following way:

```
string str = TwitterAPI(Request.QueryString["screen_name"].ToString(), "10");
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(str);
```

Where `TwitterAPI()` will return the response from following Twitter API:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

Below is the detailed error:
[image: Error]

Comment: can you please post the sting that twitterapi is returning?

Comment: Run **inside your debugger**, you'll see which **property** isn't what you expect (compared to **JSON string** you're trying to deserialize).

Comment: @EhsanUllah I am running it in a loop based on different users..so I have around 120 users so it will fetch 20 tweets for each of them...

Comment: A few things to check, Are you authenticating? The documentation says you need to for this operation. Also are you exceeding the query limit? the API also mentions that there is a limit of 180 records/15min. You appear to be pulling 2400 in a loop.

Comment: @VishalSuthar as mentioned by Adriano you will have to debug it in this case to identify which property is returned as expected. By the way try changing List<int> to List<Int64>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer.

The issue was with the limitations of Twitter API as the documentation says:

> "When an application exceeds the rate limit for a given API endpoint, the Twitter API will now return an HTTP 429 error"

and I was exceeding the limit so it was giving an exception **[(429) Too Many Requests](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1)**.

If you hit the rate limit on a given endpoint, this is the body of the HTTP 429 message that you will see:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 88,
      "message": "Rate limit exceeded"
    }
  ]
}
```

So it was returning only an error message in JSON format and it was passing it to Deserialize function which in turn giving that error.

Thanks all for your suggestions.